# Mysql trigger after inserting into 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have some problem in creating trigger that executes after insertion is completed in 2 tables.

```
"insert into table_products values (NULL, '$product_name', '$product_description', '$image_path', '$brand_id', 1)";

"insert into table_product_categories values ($product_id, '$subcatty_id')";
```

Once these 2 queries are executed i want to hit a trigger:

```
UPDATE table_product_count SET count = count + 1 WHERE brand_id = NEW.brand_id && category_id = NEW.category_id;
```

Problem is that NEW.brand_id wont be available at this moment.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join`.  Say `new` refers to `table_product_categories`:

```
UPDATE table_product_count pc JOIN
       table_products p
       on p.product_id = pc.product_id and p.brand_id = pc.brand_id            
    SET pc.count = pc.count + 1
    WHERE p.product_id = NEW.product_id AND pc.category_id = NEW.category_id;
```